# how to change the text color of navigation bar

Tags: css, html, colors, textcolor

I want the Data, Graph, Map, Table text color to be blue. Below is my code. I am new to HTML and CSS

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
 <div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Data<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="csv">
          <li><a href="#">cartodb_test1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Graph</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="drop">Table</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Below is my css part

```
.nav.navbar-nav li a {
color: blue;
```

}

My result:
[image]

Comment: **Where is the existing non-Bootstrap CSS? What have you tried?** It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Which works fine - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MaXoKr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed below: Other styles are overridding yours, if you really need to override the color you can use !important.

```
.navbar-nav a{
  color: dodgerblue !important;
}
.dropdown-menu a{
  color: grey !important;
}
```

Comment: I could not get it changed. My snapshot is attached.

Comment: @harinish Are you using bootstrap? because if you are you need to be more specific to override the bootstap styles. or use !important rules. I edited my code above.

Comment: I could get only the items listed in the dropdown as blue :-(

Comment: You clearly have other style sheets loaded, make sure you are calling this style sheet last, if it doesn't work you can add !important. like this: 

`color: grey !important;`

But try to use important only for emergencies if you can.

Comment: I will edit my answer above, please mark it as answered :)